# Cannot Add the AdSense API in API Manager

Tags: adsense-api

I'm trying to follow the AdSense API getting started guide, and I'm getting stuck on the 'Register your application' section.

I have created a project, but I can't find the 'Activate' button. Instead I go to the API Manager, and then the Library tab, where there is a ton of API's listed.

When I click 'AdSense Management API', the site eventually reports 'The API "adsense" doesn't exist or you don't have permission to access it', after about a minute of processing.

I tried adding in the analytics API, and it worked just fine.

Is there a step I'm missing? Do I need to submit an application to Google somewhere?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 33):

This was a silly mistake. The browser I was using ad adblock installed. Disabled adblocking for this site, and everything is fine.